# Facebook-Like URLS

Tags: javascript, url

I have been searching for a method of encoding url just like facebook's. All I have been able to find is these methods:

```
escape
encodeURI
encodeURIComponent
```

The goal is to encode a string in latin characters, for example:

```
¿Cómo estás?
```

Facebook results in the next url
[image]

When I use the 3 functions I talked abour earlier I get nothing similar

```
escape("¿Cómo estás?"); //"%BFC%F3mo%20est%E1s%3F"
encodeURI("¿Cómo estás?");//"%C2%BFC%C3%B3mo%20est%C3%A1s?"
encodeURIComponent("¿Cómo estás?"); //"%C2%BFC%C3%B3mo%20est%C3%A1s%3F"
```

I need you to guide me to the solution, this is something im doing more than anything for SEO purposes. Do I have to code a function myself?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my first guess is you are encoding in UTF-8 where Facebook may be encoding in ISO.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1 vs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

As far as SEO goes - I do not see the relation, the example is just a query string - so wouldn't be crawled by a search engine. I may be misunderstanding - hopefully that points you in the right direction though.

Comment: Thanks, I think you gave me a good point of view, Since my goal was a better SEO you made me see something I had to see.

Answer (score 0):

After I decided to make my search just encoding my string using `encodeURIComponent` I discovered that when you `window.location.href` your encoded string your URL actually looks like facebooks. What a surprise, It looks very different in the console.

[image]

Comment: My guess is it has something to do with browser or system localization settings.